# How to run a Selenium testNG file from Command Line with multiple packages?

Tags: java, selenium, command, testng, line

I am having trouble running my testNG xml file from the command line due the main Selenium Java tests having multiple packages.

I have a package called webDrivertests, which includes the java class that contains the methods the xml file runs, called LoadConfigModels.java.

The xml file is parallelLoadConfig.xml.

In LoadConfigModels.java, I import another package called utility, which contains a  class called ExcelUtils.java that I use to parse an excel sheet.

Here is the batch file I'm using:

```
set projectLocation=C:\Users\user_name\eclipse-workspace\Test_Scripts
cd/
cd %projectLocation%
set classpath=%projectLocation%\bin;%projectLocation%\lib\*
java org.testng.TestNG %projectLocation%\parallelLoadConfig.xml
pause
```

Here is a directory:

--> Project Name: Test_Scripts

----> Package: utility

--------> ExcelUtils.java

----> Package: webDrivertests

--------> LoadConfigModels.java

Everything runs smoothly until the code reaches the Excel.utils call and crashes. The code runs fine when running in eclipse. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: post the exception...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle your problem is to use Maven/Gradle to build the project and launch tests.

https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/maven-project-setup-for-selenium-selenium-tutorial-24/

Comment: Maven is currently not an option for due to corporate restrictions. Is there a way to do this using command line prompts?